# Updating option menu item which is currently showing

Tags: android, user-interface, menu

Because of some reasons, some menu item is disabled and will be enabled after the data is arrived.
Here is the case that I conern:
When the menu is **current showing** to user and the data is arrived, how can I enable the menu item instantly?

Now I only enable/disable menu item in onPrepareOptionsMenu(), it is only called when menu is shown again.  FYI, I am using android 2.x SDK

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the opPrepareOptionsMenu is called, it gets a reference to the Menu, so you can save this reference in a Variable, and when the data is ready add or enable de option again.

Comment: I have try this method, but it always return NullPointerException when accessing the menu reference...
Is that the reference will be point to null when it is not showing?

Comment: yes, is possible that it would be null if is not in the screen

Answer (score 0):

I have already done this and it is working fine. Take a look at this code...

While creating your menu add different group to each of your menu option so that you can easily handle each button seperately.  like : I am giving you example of hold and resume button. One time only one button will work so how to do that here is code.

Declare this in your class.

```
private static final int HOLD_CALL      = 0;
private static final int RESUME_CALL    = 1;
```

Write this code in your   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)

```
menu.add(0, HOLD_CALL, 0, "Hold Call");
menu.add(1, RESUME_CALL, 1, "Resume Call");
```

Use this in your public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu)

```
menu.setGroupEnabled(1, false);`
```

the above code will  disable your menu option. Hope it will help you If still you are facing problem then let me know i will try to help you...

Comment: Sorry, I am asking edit the menu item when the menu is showing to user
Therefore, they key point should be how to store the menu reference instead of how to edit it...

Comment: When you want it when user click on menu button or when menu have  already displayed on screen at that time.